# After Task starts, it displays only if calling another method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, console-application

```
void Something() => System.Console.WriteLine("Something is done");
Task t = new Task(delegate {Something();});
t.Start();  // nothing activates unless the below code is uncommented
// System.Console.WriteLine(33);  //displays "33 \nSomething is done" as long as not commented out
```

I don't understand something fundamental about Task.  In the code above, if line 4 is commented out, nothing is written on the console, but if you write in `System.Console.WriteLine(33)`, then the number 33 displays AND `"Something is done"` displays.

1. I don't understand why `t.Start()` doesn't write `"Something is done"`.
2. Why does writing anything after `t.Start()`, activate it?

Thank you.

---

**Update:** This is my whole program. It is intended to understand the behavior of `Task`, so the program is small.

Comment: Is this your whole program? You start the task and then the program terminates?

Comment: Yes.  It's intended to understand the behavior of Task, so the program is small.

Comment: You are not going to learn anything useful. You have a race condition: the program wants to terminate, and the task wants to run. Either can win the race, depending on factors deterministic or not. Let's say that you study these factors, and reach a solid conclusion. In which case are you going to make use of this knowledge? Are you planning to create many programs whose constituent elements are battling and undermining each other?

Comment: Different people learn in different ways.  I like to understand the fundamentals as much as possible from the very start.  But that's just me.  fwiw, I learned a lot here, and I really appreciate your input.  You have a good point, but that is how I learn, and this really helped me a lot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thread does not block and hence is exiting immediately without `Console.WriteLine`. `Console.WriteLine` is done on the main thread.

Since this is a console app, the call to the Wait method is necessary to prevent the app from terminating before the task finishes execution.

```
t.Start();
t.Wait();
```

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-start

Another way is to make the Main method async.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Task t = new Task(delegate { Something(); });
    t.Start();
    await t;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, this does not explain the behavior.  It seems that the program ends before the Task t completes, and so the Task is not completed.  However, when you place the Console.WriteLine ABOVE the t.Start(), then the Task t finishes, but I don't see why it would, if it is starting AFTER Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @richalot updated te answer

Comment: REALLY sorry.  I think I am missing something obvious.  If you use Console.WriteLine anywhere in the program, you don't need to use t.wait(), and it still runs correctly.  Yet, by your answer above, that should not be the case.  So I guess my question is, if using Console.WriteLine anywhere on the program allows it to finish properly, why?  What does Console.WriteLine, even in the beginning of the program, have anything to do with the Task?

Comment: Because Console.WriteLine runs on the main thread. This program is so fast it exits quickly. In case of Console.WriteLine it gets enough time

Comment: @richalot you can try creating the method asynchrony and put Task.Delay and see the behaviour with Console.WriteLine

Comment: Thank you.  That was what I was missing.  Just slowing the main thread down in any way is what is allowing time for the Task to complete.